# Istio VirtualService rewrite prefix works like exact match

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, amazon-eks

I am using istio and running a service on path "/" and "/app" and both "/" and "/app" will serve same page. Achieving this, I have added rewrite rule on "/app" to "/" and it works fine.

But when I am trying to hit "/app/login", rewrite do not serve page "/login".

```
    - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: /app
      rewrite:
        uri: /
      route:
      - destination:
          host: app-svc
          port:
            number: 8000
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/8076) discusses this behavior. Your current rule will rewrite `/app/login` to `//login` instead of `/login`. Apparently duplicate slashes are not ignored automatically. The best solution right now is to tweak your rule as mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/8076#issuecomment-427057691):

> ```
> - match:
>   - uri:
>       prefix: "/app/"
>   - uri:
>       prefix: "/app"
>   rewrite:
>     uri: "/"
> ```